Verses on efficacy of prayer over rituals
Whatever little amount of scripture has been read shows that while they speak much on importance of rituals, sadācāra & siddhānta, very few mentions were obtained about prayer. In these times, prayer is often touted as an all-round solution for all types of spiritual woes & ritualistic approaches are often met with suspicion. For those who are unable to organise elaborate rituals, the Haribhaktivilāsa advocates contributing money & material & at the least, viewing the rituals, but no mention of prayer was found. Can anybody provide quotation from the scriptures discussing efficiency of prayer over ritual ?

In the bhakti scriptures (e.g.,. Bhagavata Purana), offering prayers is known as Vandanam. It isn't compared with other practices but is said to be sufficient in itself for salvation. Glories of chanting Nama is also extensively described which is internally the same as offering prayers to God. Both of these do not depend on any rituals and are fully independent practices by themselves.

Please do cite the specific verses.

Vandanam is in the Bhagavatam as one of the navadha bhakti. The equal efficacy of all the nine types of bhakti is in the Chaitanya Charitamrta. People on this site seem to lack faith in devotional literature. If you're open to them, let me know and I'll cite them.

I am agreeable with the Srimad Bhagavatam. Please do quote the relevant verses in your answer.

The efficacy of spiritual practices depends on the Deity being propitiated and the purpose behind the practice (e.g., to fulfill a specific material desire or to be liberated from material life).
To attain liberation or Mokṣa, the Shrimad Bhagavatam teaches Bhakti (devotional services) which is an activity of the mind and the Bhagavatam speaks little about performance of elaborate rituals. Only shraddhā (firm faith or conviction) in the power of devotional service is required.
As per the Bhagavatam, the child devotee Prahlāda, who had received the darshan of Lord Narasimhadeva describes nine different processes of devotional service and one of them is Vandanam or offering prayers (Prahlāda had perfected Smaranam or constant remembrance of Lord Viṣṇu).
श्रीप्रह्राद उवाच
श्रवणं कीर्तनं विष्णो: स्मरणं पादसेवनम् ।
अर्चनं वन्दनं दास्यं सख्यमात्मनिवेदनम् ॥ २३ ॥
इति पुंसार्पिता विष्णौ भक्तिश्चेन्नवलक्षणा ।
क्रियेत भगवत्यद्धा तन्मन्येऽधीतमुत्तमम् ॥ २४ ॥


Prahlāda Mahārāja said: Hearing and chanting about the transcendental
holy name, form, qualities, paraphernalia and pastimes of Lord Viṣṇu,
remembering them, serving the lotus feet of the Lord, offering the
Lord respectful worship with sixteen types of paraphernalia, offering
prayers to the Lord, becoming His servant, considering the Lord one’s
best friend, and surrendering everything unto Him (in other words,
serving Him with the body, mind and words) — these nine processes are
accepted as pure devotional service. One who has dedicated his life to
the service of Kṛṣṇa through these nine methods should be understood
to be the most learned person, for he has acquired complete knowledge.

Following any of the abovementioned nine processes is sufficient to realize the Absolute Truth.
श्री विष्णोः श्रवणे परीक्षिद् अभवद् वैयासकिः कीर्तने
प्रह्लादः स्मरणे तद्-अङ्घ्रि-भजने लक्ष्मीः पृथुः पूजने ।
अक्रूरस् त्व् अभिवन्दने कपि-पतिर् दास्ये’थ सख्ये’र्जुनः
सर्वस्वात्म-निवेदने बलिर् अभूत् कृष्णाप्तिर् एषां परा 


“Parīkṣit is an example of hearing about the Lord and Śukadeva is an
example of chanting about the glories of the Lord. Prahlāda is an
example of remembering the Lord and Lakṣmī is an example of serving
the lotus feet of the Lord. Pṛthu is an example of performing Deity
worship of the Lord. Akrūra is an example of attaining perfection by
offering prayers to the Lord. Hanumān is an example of service with
an attitude of a servant of the Lord. Arjuna is an example of
friendship with the Lord. Bali is an example of offering oneself to
the Lord. They achieved Kṛṣṇa by following principally one aṅga.”

Another example of attaining salvation through Vandanam is Gajendra who could only offer his heartfelt prayers being an elephant and Lord Hari appeared before him.
When Gajendra prayed to the Supreme Being to be freed from the attack of the crocodile, he was unclear of who that Supreme Being was and thus not situated in proper sadācāra or understanding of siddhānta. This is explained in the below verses.
श्रीशुक उवाच
एवं गजेन्द्रमुपवर्णितनिर्विशेषं
ब्रह्मादयो विविधलिङ्गभिदाभिमाना: ।
नैते यदोपससृपुर्निखिलात्मकत्वात्
तत्राखिलामरमयो हरिराविरासीत् ॥ ३० ॥


Śrī Śukadeva Gosvāmī continued: When the King of the elephants was
describing the supreme authority, without mentioning any particular
person, he did not invoke the demigods, headed by Lord Brahmā, Lord
Śiva, Indra and Candra. Thus none of them approached him. However,
because Lord Hari is the Supersoul, Puruṣottama, the Personality of
Godhead, He appeared before Gajendra.
From the description of Gajendra, he apparently was aiming at the
supreme authority although he did not know who the supreme authority
is. He conjectured, “There is a supreme authority who is above
everything.” Under the circumstances, the Lord’s various expansions,
such as Lord Brahmā, Lord Śiva, Candra and Indra, all thought,
“Gajendra is not asking our help. He is asking the help of the
Supreme, who is above all of us.”

तं तद्वदार्तमुपलभ्य जगन्निवास:
स्तोत्रं निशम्य दिविजै: सह संस्तुवद्भ‍ि: ।
छन्दोमयेन गरुडेन समुह्यमान-
श्चक्रायुधोऽभ्यगमदाशु यतो गजेन्द्र: ॥ ३१ ॥


After understanding the awkward condition of Gajendra, who had offered
his prayers, the Supreme Personality of Godhead, Hari, who lives
everywhere, appeared with the demigods, who were offering prayers to
Him. Carrying His disc and other weapons, He appeared there on the
back of His carrier, Garuḍa, with great speed, according to His
desire. Thus He appeared before Gajendra.

सोऽन्त:सरस्युरुबलेन गृहीत आर्तो
द‍ृष्ट्वा गरुत्मति हरिं ख उपात्तचक्रम् ।
उत्क्षिप्य साम्बुजकरं गिरमाह कृच्छ्रा-
न्नारायणाखिलगुरो भगवन् नमस्ते ॥ ३२ ॥


Gajendra had been forcefully captured by the crocodile in the water
and was feeling acute pain, but when he saw that Nārāyaṇa, wielding
His disc, was coming in the sky on the back of Garuḍa, he immediately
took a lotus flower in his trunk, and with great difficulty due to his
painful condition, he uttered the following words: “O my Lord,
Nārāyaṇa, master of the universe, O Supreme Personality of Godhead, I
offer my respectful obeisances unto You.”

